# Kali Linux Filesystem Hierarchy Standard

Tags: filesystems

As per the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard for Linux , there exits a Requirement i.e
**There must be no subdirectories in /bin**

But in my Kali Linux [Linux kali 5.10.0-kali7-amd64] there exist a sub-directory in /bin folder i.e X11

[image] 
**So should we conclude that Kali Linux Doesn't follow FHS ?** 
Reference - https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs-3.0.pdf  [Page 5]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a folder, this is a link. A link is a file linking to another file. [Here is a link to a webpage explaining what are links in more detail.](https://www.linux.com/topic/desktop/understanding-linux-links/)